# create failed UserPoolClientLambda AWS::Lambda::Function. Resource handler returned message null

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am new to AWS services. And getting errors like Unable to push amplify initialize project in console with (amplify push command). Initializing amplify backend in react project is ok.
But creating amplify project in console is not ok. And showing me error like "**Setting up amplify studio is failed**".